# Facebook PHP SDK - getting Public Profile & Profile Image together

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

im using facebook php sdk and i follow this site http : //www.benmarshall.me/facebook-sdk-php-v4/ to use it.

Im doing two way to get facebook user info and image.

This is how i getting user public profile info

```
  $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $request = $request->execute();

  // Get response as an array
  $picture = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Returning

```
Array
(
    [id] => ***********
    [email] => *************
    [first_name] => Åahin
    [gender] => male
    [last_name] => Deniz
    [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/**********/
    [locale] => tr_TR
    [name] => Åahin Deniz
    [timezone] => 3
    [updated_time] => 2014-08-17T00:53:21+0000
    [verified] => 1
)
```

And this is the profile image connection.

```
  $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/picture?type=large&redirect=false' );
  $request = $request->execute();

  // Get response as an array
  $picture = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Returning this

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/*****************.jpg
    [is_silhouette] => 
)
```

---

My question is, how can i get this results together in one query/connection?

Like

```
Array
(
    [id] => ***********
    [email] => *************
    [first_name] => Åahin
    [gender] => male
    [last_name] => Deniz
    [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/**********/
    [locale] => tr_TR
    [name] => Åahin Deniz
    [timezone] => 3
    [updated_time] => 2014-08-17T00:53:21+0000
    [verified] => 1

    [url] => https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/*****************.jpg
)
```

---

After the comments, i understand that i cant do it with 1 query.
Also i decide to use like this

```
$User = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me' );
$Picture = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/picture?type=large&redirect=false' );
$User=array_merge($User->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray(),$Picture->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray());
```

Comment: I'm gonna go with "you can't".

Comment: is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Well, no. They're 2 separate queries. That's the whole point of the thing. They're so different that you can't do them in 1 query. But honestly do you really need 1? 2 will do just fine. It's not like three's a HUUUGE performance loss.

Comment: Plus a local cache would save subsequent requests

Comment: I know but i need only user id and image url. just two result. I can use two query but im just wondered can i do this in one query. thats all

Comment: Yes we get that, and the answer is no. And the commentary, is that it's not a big deal to have two calls. What is your concern?